# scroll navbar out of view when page is ready using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="navbar"> ... </div>
<div id="mainpage" style="height: 100vh;"> ... </div>
<div id="footer"> ... </div>
```

when the page is ready, i want the jquery to scroll out the **complete** `navbar` div, for this,
i am currently using -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navHeight = $('#navbar').height();
    console.log(navHeight);
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: navHeight}, 400); 
})
```

this only lefts some portion of navbar in view,
there is enough area left in footer to scroll.

i dont now why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var navHeight = $('#navbar').css("height","100%");
    console.log(navHeight);
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: navHeight}, 400); 
})
```